# Find and set height

Tags: jquery, height, parent-child

I try to get the height of a li element and want to set it to the child div.

**http://jsfiddle.net/h0jjt1t7/**

What i got so far. Now i have the heigth of the first element. But i want the height of the parent element.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var height = $("div").parent("li").height();
    $("div").height(height);
});


<ul>
<li>Content<br>Content<br>Content
    <div>O</div>
</li>
<li>Content<br>Content
    <div>O</div>
</li>
<li>Content
    <div>O</div>
</li>
```

Comment: `$('div').parent().height()` will suffice

Comment: don't work for me. Here have a look -> http://jsfiddle.net/h0jjt1t7/1/

Comment: I'm struggling to understand exactly what it is you're trying to do - could you explain a little bit more please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting the height of each `div` element to the height of the first `li` element. You need to set the height based on the context of each `div` element:

```
$('li > div').height(function(){
    return $(this).parent('li').height();
});
```

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/cetL9zog/)